If i copy paste a image file to React #quill editor How to prevent appearing it in editor
If i copy paste a image file to React #quill editor How to prevent appearing it in editor where iam showing file at another area instead of quill editor
All files were not taking such as .pdf, .svd
only file with image extenstions were appering at editor section
